# Accordion style behaviour on items outside of containing div

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images - 3 in each row.

I then have 3 divs directly below that with corresponding info to each of the images

I have 3 rows of images with the same setup. Essentially I want to have all items show up in a grid. If item 1,2 or 3 are clicked i want to show their related info directly below the first row of images, but before the second row of images, as well to only allow one one information div to be open at a time.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="assets/img/rpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="assets/img/mpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="assets/img/cpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="accord-content span12">
                        This is the content for the first image.
                    </div>
                    <div class="accord-content span12">
                        This is the content for the second image.
                    </div>
                    <div class="accord-content span12">
                        This is the content for the third image.
                    </div>
```

I had been using an accordion script for this however it only allows the div to be placed directly below the referencing link. Is there a way to allow external divs

```
$(".thumbnails .accord-header").click(function() {
                if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
                    $(this).next("div").slideUp("slow");
                } else {
                    $(".thumbnails .accord-content").slideUp("slow");
                    $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
                }
            });
```

Comment: ur script is totally wrong according to your structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `next div` you need to find find the ancestor and get the next one..

Replace

```
$(this).next("div")
```

with

```
$(this)..closest('li').next("li").find('div')
```

And you have invalid `HTML`  .. Only `li` should be a direct child of an `ul` .Move the div's to outside the `ul`

Why don't you have the `accordcontent` div's inside the div in the first place.
That should be the better approach.

**Approach 1**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/rpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/mpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/cpic.jpg" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
    <div class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the first image.
    </div>
    <div class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the second image.
    </div>
    <div class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the third image.
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".thumbnails .accord-header").click(function () {
    var $closestli = $(this).closest('li'),
        liIndex = $('li').index($closestli);

    // Hide all content
    var $contentDiv = $('.accord-content.span12', '.content').eq(liIndex);
    if ($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
        $contentDiv.slideUp("slow");
    } else {
        $('.accord-content.span12', '.content').not($contentDiv).slideUp("slow");
        $contentDiv.slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/423gQ/)**

**Approach 2**

Otherwise you can use HTML data-5* attributes that hold the corresponding content div to be managed.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/rpic.jpg" data-div="content1" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/mpic.jpg" data-div="content2" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="assets/img/cpic.jpg" data-div="content3" alt="" class="accord-header">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
    <div id="content1" class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the first image.
    </div>
    <div id="content2" class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the second image.
    </div>
    <div id="content3" class="accord-content span12">
        This is the content for the third image.
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".thumbnails .accord-header").click(function () {
    var contentId = $(this).data('div'),
        $contentDiv = $('#' + contentId);

    if ($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
        $contentDiv.slideUp("slow");
    } else {
        $('.accord-content.span12', '.content').not($contentDiv).slideUp("slow");
        $contentDiv.slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/423gQ/1/)**

**JS slideToggle**

```
$(".thumbnails .accord-header").click(function () {
    var contentId = $(this).data('div'),
        $contentDiv = $('#' + contentId);

        $contentDiv.slideToggle("slow");
        $('.accord-content.span12', '.content').not($contentDiv).slideUp("slow");
});
```

**[Slide Toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/423gQ/2/)**

Comment: I have tried these modifications. The main problem is I need the accord-content to span the full page. And the list items only span 33% of the page. I forgot my closing /ul in my html in the original question, the divs are outside the list.

Comment: Then you can come up with 2 methods.. Let me try something

Comment: That is an elegant solution using the html5, will work well with my php code. Thank you for completing the code, I was at a definite block in the road,

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: one further question, i was originally trying to use the .slideToggle function, would that have worked as well? Or was I butting my head against a wall there?

Comment: You were using `slideToggle` in the wrong place.. Try this if you want to use slideToggle.. It will also save 2 lines of code :)  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/423gQ/2/